# What is difference between php include_path Local Value and Master Value?

Tags: php, apache, pear

I am trying to use PEAR classses.

When i check phpinfopear path is in master value , but not in Local value.
What is the difference?

How can i check pear is enabled or not?

In php 5.3 Phar and pear are same or not?

If any one can provide a very simple program to check that am able to include pear class and working fine will be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHAR (PHP archive) is only a way to deploy php application in an archived form. PEAR (PHP Extension and Application Repository) doesn't have anything to do with that.

The master value is the one that is set in php.ini whereas the local value can come from your vhost config, .user.ini (in PHP 5.3) or even be set by your own script using `ini_set`.

Comment: Thank You. valuable simple info :-) tell something about pear. good or bad ?

Comment: "Depends", there a good packages in PEAR and there are some very old, unmaintained packages that I wouldn't use :)

Comment: @zod - Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer is no longer supported; but will still generate xls files. You have been recommended PHPExcel in the past for writing Excel files... any particular reason why you haven't taken that advice?

Comment: @Mark Yes we discuss this in past, i know PHPExcel is powerful and best one.But boss people dont want to download and  add external projects , its size and all . so i thought of pear as pear comes along with php :-(

Answer (score 1):

PEAR classes are plain PHP code and you don't need to install anything in order to use them. PEAR provides a command line installer that takes care of downloading all required stuff, dependencies and all, but it's basically a commodity.

I assume that you want to add your PEAR directory to the [include_path](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) directive so PEAR code actually works (PEAR makes heavy use of it when including files). You can do so with the [set_include_path()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) function. If you run phpinfo() to see current values, you should see the system-wide default value in the *Master* column and your local changes in the *Local* column.

As about [PHAR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php), it's an archive format to pack PHP code.

Comment: Thank You. valuable simple info :-) tell something about pear. good or bad ?